# Ionic 2 - Angular 4 Query String $http.get parameters

Tags: angular, ionic2

I couldn't find what I was looking for and therefore wanted to ask how to send a request to a JSON api with parameters.

The important thing is that the parameters need to be encoded.
The query will contain a string which could contain any characters (+, &, " ...). So it is important that it doesn't interfere with the query string.

It would like so: (Just with the query included)

```
    this.http.get('https://abcdefg.com/setting').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

The Query parameters could be:

ssid: WiFi-Network
pass: &aBc+1234567890

I would appreciate a solution.

CrypticPug

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent ?

Comment: @Maximus Thanks. That helped. Now I can just put the query parameters just into the URL String without any more changes. Super!

Comment: you're welcome, I can post it as answer if helped

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *Maximus*, I found the solution.

### Instead of dealing with parameter objects and so on I just did this:

```
    this.http.get('https://your-url.com/?key1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&key2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2) ).map(res => 

    });
```

That's all you need. The Parameters are **encoded**, so there is no problem with & or + in the query.

.

Thanks!

Cryptic Pug

Comment: You could also use `URLSearchParams` which is available, so that you do not need to manually build the url. You can well use `encodeURIComponent` with that :)